# Need help for the signals question

Tags: signal, signal-processing

Assuming that the signal x(t) is an energy-type signal and its energy is Ex= 2, what is the energy of signal -2x (t - 1)?

My step was to find the x(t) graph, the amplitude would be 2 due to the energy for Ex for x(t) is 2, then from Ex, I change the wave to =2x(t-1), but how do I calculate to solve the energy for the 2nd signal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The energy of a signal can according to Lathi (pp. 52) be calculated using the following: -

$$E_f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^2(t) \: \text{d}t $$
In your case, the function duration is only from -1.5 to -0.5 sec, so the integral is reduced to
$$E_f = \int_{-1.5\text{s}}^{-0.5\text{s}}\bigg(-2x(t-1) \bigg)^2 \: \text{d}t $$

Note that the equation only holds for real-valued signals. For complex signals simply change \$f^2(t)\$ to \$|f(t)|^2\$.